# Resize columns not working in wpf DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to make data grid columns re-sizable based on it's content. I have tried setting CanUserResizeColumns to true but it's not working. If i put this in new wpf project then it would work perfectly but in my exisiting wpf project it's not working.

Here's what I am doing :

```
<UserControl>
 <Grid>
   <ScrollViewer
    <DataGrid Name="dgAllJob" CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                                  Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Parent.ActualWidth}"                                    
                                    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"                                   
                                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"   
                                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
                                    ColumnWidth="*"                                    
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"          
                                    CanUserAddRows="False"                 
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                  CanUserSortColumns="False">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job No"  Binding="{Binding JobNumber,Mode=OneTime}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="Collapsed" Header="Start Date" Width="80" Binding="{Binding ActualStartDate,StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy,Mode=OneTime}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Client Name" Binding="{Binding BillName,Mode=OneTime}" CanUserResize="True"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Postal Address"  Binding="{Binding BillAddress,Mode=OneTime}" CanUserResize="True"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Suburb"  CanUserResize="True" Binding="{Binding BillSuburb,Mode=OneTime}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Site Suburb" CanUserResize="True" Binding="{Binding SiteSuburb,Mode=OneTime}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Contact Name" Binding="{Binding ContactName,Mode=OneTime}" CanUserResize="True"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Estimator"  Binding="{Binding Estimator,Mode=OneTime}" CanUserResize="True"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Installer" Binding="{Binding Installer,Mode=OneTime}" CanUserResize="True"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
     </ScrollViewer>
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

can anyone tell what I am missing or what is wrong here ???

Comment: I think by default the DataGrid CAN resize. Have you tried removing CanUserResizeColumns? Maybe instead of setting it to true you can set the columns to false where you don't want resizing? Of course, this is all based on the assumption that risizing is default behavior.

Comment: Do you have any custom styles in your exisiting project? These may disable the resize functionality. Try to for example set the `ColumnHeaderStyle` property to `x:Null`.

Comment: You don't need to set `CanUserResize="True"` in `DataGridTextColumn`. And you have `ColumnWidth="*"` in the `DataGrid`, you will not be able to resize the columns because it will not go beyond the size of window. Just try removing the ColumnWidth property or set it to `Auto`.

Comment: @mm8 Yes Exactly It was not working becauase of the default style which was applied to DataGridColumnHeader. It worked after i removed that style..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any custom styles in your exisiting project may disable the resize functionality.

You could try to for example set the `ColumnHeaderStyle` property to `x:Null` or simply remove the custom `Style`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are putting your DataGrid in a ScrollViewer, the DataGrid will be sized to the minimum. Try disabling the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility or take it out of the ScrollViewer.